# How to change sculpt expand shapes without numpad?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, masking

I'm trying to learn blender sculpt expand feature. I would like to change shape of the mask, normaly you can do this by pressing numpad-2, 3 etc.

I have no numpad, and I'm emulating it, but pressing numerical keys doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: I have a numpad and pressing num-2, num-3 does not change the shape of the mask for me, it changes the view angle. Which is normal. What do you mean change the shape? Change the falloff? Grow or shrink the mask?

Comment: True, you need to use nummercal keys not numpad, so i formed my question wrong. Anyway, when  you are emulating numpad it doesn't work. https://youtu.be/XT7h6lmE5bc - 14:30